# htmlunit and document.addEventListener

Tags: jquery, htmlunit, addeventlistener

I'm a newbie to HtmlUnit.  Please excuse me if this has already been asked and answered.

I'm having trouble getting HtmlUnit to work with pages that use JQuery.  To be more precise, I'm having trouble getting HtmlUnit to work with any JS code that uses document.addEventListener(), such as JQuery.  For example, the following page works in a browser, but not HtmlUnit:

```
<html><head>
<script>
  function atest() {}
  document.addEventListener( "load", atest, false );
</script>
</head>
<body>This page will load in a browser, but not HtmlUnit.</body></html>
```

The resulting error is:

```
======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[5] column=[0] lineSource=[<no source>] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[script in http://myhost:8080/mpt/dummy from (3, 9) to (6, 10)] message=    [TypeError: Cannot find function addEventListener in object [object]. (script in     http://myhost:8080/mpt/dummy from (3, 9) to (6, 10)#5)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function addEventListener in object [object]. (script in http://myhost:8080/mpt/dummy from (3, 9) to (6, 10)#5)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:705)
…
```

I've tried a few different versions of JQuery and HtmlUnit.  I'm sure HtmlUnit works with JQuery (doesn't it?), but there might be a catch that I don't know about.  So hints appreciated.  My JUnit code, if relevant, is:

```
@Test
public void test() throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.getPage("http://myhost:8080/mpt/dummy");
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yup,  seems that html unit has a bug.

https://github.com/searls/jasmine-maven-plugin/issues/135

In the end, I customized my Jasmin maven plugin to run my javascript tests using the phantom js headless browser.

http://searls.github.io/jasmine-maven-plugin/phantomjs.html

If you are using maven lower than 3.1, i am using 3.0.4 right now, you cannot use the maven plugin that automatically installs the phanom js browser for you. In this case, go the web side and download it by hand.

Put somehting like this in your maven configuration.

```
<webDriverClassName>org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver</webDriverClassName>
                        <webDriverCapabilities>
                            <capability>
                                <name>phantomjs.binary.path</name>
                                <value>D:\phantomjs-1.9.8\phantomjs.exe</value>
                              </capability>                             
                        </webDriverCapabilities>
```

See if your tests are more successful without html unit.

You can also try to upgrade html unit to the latest release, or play with their browser emulation.
In my case, the error persisted, and I swapped for the ghosty.

Cheers.